# flutter auto click on html element loaded in webview

Tags: flutter

I want to get all elements in a document loaded in flutter webview and then click on a html element. How can I do it?

My webview code:

```
//WebView
          WebView(
            initialUrl: "url",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c){
              controller = c;
            },
            onPageStarted: (String s) async {
              setState(() {
                // on page started codes
              });
            },
            onPageFinished: (String s) async {
              setState(() {
                // on page finished codes
              });
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WebViewController.runJavascript()

Qustion 1 solution(get elements in loaded document(string)):

```
controller.runJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].InnerHTML");
```

Question 2 solution(click on a html element):

```
controller.runJavascript("document.getElementById('btnId').click()");
```