# Programmatically search Google through WebView - Flutter / DART

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, dom

I am using Flutter to build an app to search Google for me (so that I don't have to). I want it to search 'How many golf balls fit in a bus'. I have a WebView and want to add text into the search box when the Google Landing Page loads. How may I go about doing that?

What I have so far doesn't seem to do anything - it doesn't enter the details in the search box. (and I can't seem to see any feedback, errors or alerts when I test it).

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: this.widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
        },
        onPageFinished: (String s) {
          setState(() {
            _controller.evaluateJavascript("window.addEventListener('load', function () {document.getElementsByTagName('q')[0].value += 'How many golf balls fit in a bus'})");
            _controller.evaluateJavascript("window.addEventListener('load', function () {document.getElementsByTagName('btnK')[0].click})");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have looked at this already: [flutter auto click on html element loaded in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086943/flutter-auto-click-on-html-element-loaded-in-webview)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `getElementsByTagName` method, You have to use `getElementsByName` instead.

You can try this yourself, open the browser,open inspect element and then console tab and past `document.getElementsByTagName('q')[0].value += 'How many golf balls fit in a bus'` , nothing will happen, you can also check the result of `getElementsByTagName` , you can notice it is an empty array.